# Name for the future time period with the creation/surpassing of artifical intelligence?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to know the term or time period to come that means the creation or surpassing of Artificial Intelligence. I know that there are different time periods humanity has gone through like the stone age, the bronze age but I need the term for a future term. I know it is out there because I watched a scishow video (youtube channel) and saw the time periods and there was a time period that is to come. It means the surpassing of artificial intelligence. I just forgot the word/term but I know what it means. I need this for a project, thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for a term relating to the real-world development of AI (off-topic), or to the AI that appears in science fiction and fictional futures (on-topic)? Also, what do you mean by "the creation or surpassing of AI"? Some AI has already *been* created in the real world, and surpassing what?

Comment: The way I see it the Technological Singularity can be the core of many sci-fi works and it's a valid question in that regard. The way the question was asked doesn't reflect this very well, though.

Comment: Yep, the term "singularity" is not simply a SciFi term, but has been adopted by the "real" technical community to refer to a future time when AI has become "smart" enough to improve on itself, presumably without bound.

Answer (score 11):

I think you’re referring to the [Technological Singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity). This is a common sci-fi or speculative-science term to the time when AI will exist and can improve itself.

Comment: Thank you good sir for telling me the name of it. I was referring to just singularity but overall thank you!